# What precautions to take if writing a virus

Tags: security, virus

If I was to Write a virus for the challenge What would I need to do to contain it ?

Obviously I would disconnect the computer from the internet first but what else could I do to prevent the worst case scenario of it making it on to the internet. 
Im not saying im smart enough to bring down society but I don't want to go to jail for a weekend project.

Is is likely that my antivirus will kill my virus program as soon as it is compiled ?

Comment: If you were a chemical engineer, would you create a deadly poison as a weekend project?  Why not work on something constructive?  :-)

Comment: @Shawn D Iv always wondered if a virus could be retrofitted to do something constructive, thinking my skill are up the the point where I can try. also yes its all about the challenge :)

Comment: @Paul I know the story from /. but I hadn't seen that :-)) Thanks.

Comment: @Skeith: You could write a virus that affects only other viruses...

Comment: +1 because this is such an amusing question, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would I need to do to contain it ?

You need to use a sandboxed environment. Perhaps a virtual machine such as vmware or virtualbox that doesn't have physical access to the network.

> Is is likely that my antivirus will kill my virus program as soon as
>   it is compiled

Not really. Antivirus programs are based on signature scanning + heuristics. Your program should be "0-day". So until it does something fishy, it's unlikely any antivirus will ask questions.

Comment: That is not totaly correct - some anti-viruses map syscall graphs and other novelties. it really depends on how the virus operates

Comment: Depending on the method/payload, virus scanners may be able to predict 'fishiness' using heuristics.  A good first test, I suppose.